# Update empty String with an onClick Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just have a small problem.

I do not know how to update my empty string when handling a `click` event. I am using React.

This is the most important part of my code:

```
// MultiStepform.js

const defaultData = {
  // I would like to update this
  Grund: '',
  H: '',
  W: '',
  G: '',
};

export const MultiStepFrom = () => {
  const [formData, setForm] = useForm(defualtData);
  const {step, navigation} = useStep({
    steps, 
    initialStep: 0,
  });

  const props = {formData, setForm, navigation};
};
```

Häuser.js

I would like to perform her the onClick event)

```
   function Häuser({formData, setForm, navigation}) {
      const {Grund, H, W, G} = formData;

          const changState = () => {
          navigation.next();
          setForm([{Grund: "newvalue"}]); 

       }
      );
       }

          return (
           <div
          className="container__containerimgage"
           name="Grundstück"
               value={Grundstück}
                onClick={changState}
                   
         );
            }
```

Comment: You can't directly set state, it's `const`. You should use the `setForm` callback. If you can update your question to include that `hook` code or what library it's imported from we can refine an answer.

Comment: I used { useForm, useStep } from 'react-hooks-helper'

Comment: Are you trying to take data from the form and feed it back to one place? This is what store/state plugins are for, so you might be better off using one. [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) is the go-to, but there are others. Alternatively, the child components could emit events up to the parent component which records the data. What you're trying to do in the provided code is essentially two-way data flow, which is one of the key things the creators React [wanted to avoid](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down).

Comment: Yes I am trying to take data from the form and update that data if I click on a image.I thought about using Redux, but I think that is the easier way. I know how to do it by using an text Input

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You can't directly manipulate state, it's `const`. You should use the state updater function.

## Solution

Use `setForm` function to update the form state.

[useForm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-helper#useform)

> You see `useForm` takes the name of your `input` and changes the object,
> so you only have to create ***one*** `useForm`.

Code

```
function Häuser({formData, setForm, navigation}) {
  const { Grund, H, W, G } = formData;

  const changeState = (changeEvent) => { // <-- new onChange event with value
    navigation.next();
    setForm(changeEvent); // <-- pass event to updater
    ...
  }

  ...

  <input
    value={Grund}
    name="Grund" // <-- ensure the input name matches field name
    onChange={changeState}
  />
```

Comment: const changState = () => {
    navigation.next();
    setForm({  Grund:"G" }); // set new value
    
  }     // Thats right ??

Comment: Sry guys I do not really understand your code I am getting the error    Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: @danielragimov You need to provide a `name` attribute for the input you are updating. Updated answer with link to documentation and brief example.

Comment: could you please post the code I am not sure what exactly you mean (I am quit new in programming)

Comment: function Häuser({formData, setForm, navigation}) {
          const {Grund, H, W, G} = formData;
 
              const changState = () => {
            navigation.next();
           setForm([{Grund: "newvalue"}]); 
    
  }
    );
  }  is that right ?

Comment: @danielragimov No, `setForm` consumes the `onChange` event and extracts the input name and updated value from it to presumably update the correct form field property in state.

Comment: I am not using onChange im using onClick

Comment: @danielragimov That hook and library appears to be geared towards updating form fields. If you aren't using inputs' `onChange` attribute then you may need to adapt your "onClick" object to match what `setForm` is expecting, i.e. an `onChange` object. Can you just update your question to include your real code then, so we can see what you're really trying to do?

Comment: Hi I have postet a update question, maybe you can help me there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65858221/how-to-use-usestate-to-update-data